# What kind of tree is this with reddish leaves?

Tags: identification, trees

This is a young tree that was planted a couple years ago. Is it possible to id from these pics?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your location? There are a few trees and shrubs with leaves that look like that, and yes dogwood is definitely one of them, but there is also a lychee lookalike that I have seen growing in the northeast USA that has very similar leaves as well. Hydrangea can also look a bit like that, but I don't think this is hydrangea.

Comment: Cleveland, Ohio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a dogwood to me, w the reddish leaves.

https://selectree.calpoly.edu/tree-detail/cornus-florida-cherokee-princess

Now that there are photos of the flowers, it's very clearly a pink dogwood.

Here is another good link w images and description from a Kansas botanical garden.

https://powellgardens.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/flowering-dogwoods-missouris-state-flower/

Comment: I added a picture of a flower from a couple weeks ago. It only had the one flower and it is gone now. Does this help?

Comment: Definitely dogwood!  Give it some mulch and it will prosper!